# Angular - Multi-select dropdown component with buttons Apply and Cancel at the bottom of the list

Tags: angular, multi-select

I need a multi-select dropdown.
With the typical `select all` option,but **it should also have two buttons at the end of the list**:

- Apply
- Cancel

Something like this image:

[image]

I found this two components :

https://nileshpatel17.github.io/ng-multiselect-dropdown/

https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

But I need a component that either have these two buttons or at least let me extend it add these buttons.

Do you know of any component similar to the one shown in the image?

Comment: Please don't close this question.

Comment: Why not try creating a custom component and then adding `ng-multiselect-dropdown` as its first child and the two buttons as the second child?

Comment: But the buttons are part of the list not the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone might find it useful. I ended up using ng-select.
Here are some examples:

[Without using reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-with-footer)

[Using reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-with-footer-reactive)